# Parse C string to numbers and operators

Tags: c, string, parsing

I need to parse the string and as a result I need an array with numbers and operators ([12, '+',45], for example).

That's how I get the string:

```
char str[100];
fgets(str, 100, stdin);
```

Here is the function for parse:

```
char* parse_string(char *string)
{
char result_digits[50][50];
char result_operators[50];
static char result_string[100];

int i = 0;
int digits_cnt = 0;
int digit_string = 0;
int operators_cnt = 0;
while (string[i] != '\n') {
    if (detect_symbol_type(string[i]) == sym_digit) {
        result_digits[digit_string][digits_cnt] = string[i];
        digits_cnt++;
    } else {
        if (detect_symbol_type(string[i]) == sym_operator) {
            result_operators[operators_cnt] = string[i];
            operators_cnt++;
            digit_string++;
            digits_cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
result_operators[operators_cnt] = '\n';

double result_numbers[100];
for (int i = 0; i <= digit_string; i++) {
    double result = 0;
    sscanf(result_digits[digit_string], "%lf", &result);
    result_numbers[i] = result;
    printf("Result: %lf\n", result);
}

int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= (digit_string + operators_cnt); i++) {
    result_string[i] = result_numbers[k];
    i++;
    result_string[i] = result_operators[k];
    k++;
}

return result_string;
}
```

It does not work. Looks like something wrong with sscanf (it can't transform string from array of string (restul_digits)).
What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted:

```
sscanf(result_digits[i], "%lf", &result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a mistake:)